# Symfony 3 problems with getting the price and name right on my checkout

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am having trouble with my shopping cart. I'm a newbie at coding and i can not get this stuff right.
So. my problem is:

I made a "webshop" with a: product list / shopping cart / checkout.

**There are 2 products:**
[image]
**When i add them to my card i get this:**
[image]
**And then there is the checkout where it goes wrong:**
[image]
You can see that it added the name and the price of the product with the ID 3 instead of adding both items correctly.

Here is my code:

#### CartController (with the checkout function)

```
<?php

namespace TuinadviesBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

use TuinadviesBundle\Entity\Product;

/**
 * @Route("/cart")
 */
class CartController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="cart")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // get the cart from  the session
//        $session = new Session();
        // $cart = $session->set('cart', '');
        $session = $this->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()->getSession();
        $cart = $session->get('cart', array());
       // $cart = $session->get('cart', array());

        // $cart = array_keys($cart);
        // print_r($cart); die;

        // fetch the information using query and ids in the cart
        if( $cart != '' ) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            foreach( $cart as $id => $quantity ) {
                $product[] = $em->getRepository('TuinadviesBundle:Product')->findById($id);
            }

            if( !isset( $product ) )
            {
                return $this->render('TuinadviesBundle:cart:index.html.twig', array(
                    'empty' => true,
                ));
            }


            return $this->render('TuinadviesBundle:Cart:index.html.twig',     array(
                'product' => $product,
            ));
        } else {
            return $this->render('TuinadviesBundle:Cart:index.html.twig',     array(
                'empty' => true,
            ));
        }
    }


    /**
     * @Route("/checkout", name="cart_checkout")
     */
    public function checkout() {
        $session = $this->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()->getSession();
        $cart = $session->get('cart', array());

        foreach( $cart as $id => $qunatity) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $product = $em->getRepository('TuinadviesBundle:Product')->find(key($cart));

        }



        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $product = $em->getRepository('TuinadviesBundle:Product')->find(key($cart));
        return $this->render('@Tuinadvies/checkout/index.html.twig',     array(
           'product' => $product,
           'price' => $product->getPrice(),
            'name' => $product->getName(),
            dump($product),
        ));






        //return $this->render('@Tuinadvies/checkout/index.html.twig',     array(
         //  'product' => $product();
       // ));


        //return $this->render('@Tuinadvies/checkout/index.html.twig',     array(
        //   'id' => $product->getId(),
        //    'price' => $product->getPrice(),
        //));



}

    /**
     * @Route("/add/{id}", name="cart_add")
     */
    public function addAction($id)
    {
        // fetch the cart
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $product = $em->getRepository('TuinadviesBundle:Product')->find($id);
        //print_r($product->getId()); die;
        $session = $this->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()->getSession();
        $cart = $session->get('cart', array());
        //$cart = $session->get('cart', array());


        // check if the $id already exists in it.
        if ( $product == NULL ) {
            $this->get('session')->setFlash('notice', 'This product is not     available in Stores');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cart'));
        } else {
            if( isset($cart[$id]) ) {

                //$qtyAvailable = $product->getQuantity();
                $qtyAvailable = 999;
                if( $qtyAvailable >= $cart[$id]  + 1 ) {
                    $cart[$id]  = $cart[$id]  + 1;
                } else {
                    $this->get('session')->setFlash('notice', 'Quantity     exceeds the available stock');
                    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cart'));
                }
            } else {
                // if it doesnt make it 1
                $cart = $session->get('cart', array());
                $cart[$id] = $id;
                $cart[$id]  = 1;
            }

            $session->set('cart', $cart);
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cart'));

        }
    }


    /**
     * @Route("/remove/{id}", name="cart_remove")
     */
    public function removeAction($id)
    {
        // check the cart
        $session = $this->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()->getSession();
        $cart = $session->get('cart', array());
        //$cart = $session->get('cart', array());

        // if it doesn't exist redirect to cart index page. end
        if(!$cart) { $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl('cart') ); }

        // check if the $id already exists in it.
        if( isset($cart[$id]) ) {
            // if it does ++ the quantity
            $cart[$id]  = '0';
            unset($cart[$id]);
            //echo $cart[$id] ; die();
        } else {
            return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl('cart') );
        }

        $session->set('cart', $cart);

        // redirect(index page)
        return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl('cart') );
    }
}
```

#### Checkout/index.html.twig

```
{% extends '@Tuinadvies/base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Checkout</h1>
    {% if empty is defined %}
        <h5>Your shopping cart is empty.</h5>
    {% endif %}

    {% set cart = app.session.get('cart') %}


    {% if product is defined %}


        <ul class="thumbnails">
        {% if app.session.flashbag.has('notice') %}

            <div class="flash-notice">

                {{app.session.flashbag.has('notice') }}

            </div>

        {% endif %}
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Price (€)</th>
        </thead>
    {% for key, item, price in cart %}
        <tr class="col-span-6">
            <td><b>{{ name }}<b></td>
            <td>{{ key }}</td>
            <td>{{ item }}</td>
            <td>{{ price }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>

        {% endif %}

    <a href="{{ path('product_index') }}">Products</a>

{% endblock %}
```

#### cart/index.html.twig

```
{% extends '@Tuinadvies/base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Winkelwagentje</h1>
    <ul class="thumbnails">

        {% if empty is defined %}
            <h5>Your shopping cart is empty.</h5>
        {% endif %}
        {% set cart = app.session.get('cart') %}


        {% if product is defined %}


            <ul class="thumbnails">
                {% if app.session.flashbag.has('notice') %}

                    <div class="flash-notice">

                        {{app.session.flashbag.has('notice') }}

                    </div>

                {% endif %}
                {% for key, item in cart %}
                    <p>ID:{{ key }}</p>
                    <p>Quantity:{{ item }}</p>
                    <a href="{{ path('cart_remove', {'id': key}) }}">Remove</a>
                    <a href="{{ path('cart_checkout', {'id': key}) }}">checkout</a>


                {% endfor %}
            </ul>

        {% endif %}
    </ul>

    <a href="{{ path('product_index') }}">Products</a>

{% endblock %}
```

There might be a lot of spaghetti code (bad code) but that's because i'm a real newbie. so sorry about that!!!

Hope anyone can help me :)

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're fetching every checked out product from the database but overwriting it then on the `$product` variable instead of saving all of them.

You should use an array to store the different products and then use those products to fill the values in your twig template

So, in your checkout action you would have something like this:

```php
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$repo = $em->getRepository('TuinadviesBundle:Product');

$products = [];
foreach ($cart as $id => $quantity) {
    $products[] = $repo->find($id);
}
```

Then, when rendering the template, just pass the `$products` array instead of the name and price.

```php
return $this->render('@Tuinadvies/checkout/index.html.twig', array(
    'products' => $products,
));
```

And finally, in your twig template, instead of iterating over the cart, you would iterate over the `products` array and use it's id to get the right quantity

```
{% for product in products %}
    <tr class="col-span-6">
        <td><b>{{ product.name }}</b></td>
        <td>{{ product.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ cart[product.id] }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.price }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephan i'm going to try it out now!

Comment: I tried it out but now i get a blank checkout without any products in it. maybe it has something to do with my cart buttons?

Comment: i'll upload the cart/index.html.twig in to my question hold on

Comment: In your original twig template I see a `{% if product is defined %}` surrounding the table, please change that to `{% if products is not empty %}` because we have removed `product` it is never defined

Comment: omg it works!!! Thanks a lot!! i could kiss you right now haha. have been struffling with this the whole day. again thanks a lot!

Comment: Now i have to make a payment function and store it in to the database. hope that goes right haha. can i contact u somewhere for if i have problems with that? :P